# Why isn't my callback being called on one page only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using jQuery to grab some JSON and then plug it into some elements and display it on my page.

It works fine on [all pages](http://www.toberua.com/~new/) except [one](http://www.toberua.com/~new/contact-us), where the response seems to be the page itself.

I have placed `alert()`s in the callbacks (`success` and `complete`) and they never seem to be fired (though Firebug shows the request returning `200 OK` which *should* trigger the `success` handler).

I don't know what to do, I've never encountered this before.

Here is the jQuery code I am using:

```
var specials = (function() {

    var specials = false,
        specialsAnchor;

    var init = function() {
        specialsAnchor = $('#menu-specials a');

        specialsAnchor.click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (specials != false && specials.is(':visible')) {
                hide();
            } else {
                show();
            }

        });
    };

    var load = function(callback) {

      specialsAnchor.addClass('loading');

      specials = $('<div />', { 'id': 'specials' }).hide().appendTo('#header');

      var specialsUl = $('<ul />').appendTo(specials);

      $.ajax(specialsAnchor.attr('href'), {
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(i, special) {

                specialsUl.append('<li><h4>' + special.heading + '</h4><p>' + special.content + '</p></li>');

            });
            specialsAnchor.removeClass('loading');
            callback.call();

         }

      });

    }

    var show = function() {
      if (specials == false) {
        load(show);
        return;
      }
      specials.slideDown(500);
    }

    var hide = function() {
      specials.slideUp(500);
    }

    $(init);

})();
```

What is going on?

Comment: where is `data.basePath` coming from... i dont see `data` defined anywhere. Nevermind.. its a global...

Comment: What @prodigitalson said, and on a side note I'd assume this is some kind of URL/hierarchy issue.

Comment: @prodigitalson It is defined in the `head` element.

Comment: @prodigitalson I changed it, but remember this is the same URL on all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you're including jquery.validate on this page, but not the others. jQuery validate with jQuery > 1.5 [causes some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276790/jquery-1-5-1-breaks-all-ajax-calls) with AJAX calls.

I realize the linked question/answer aren't exactly what you're seeing, but I've seen all kinds of weird issues with AJAX calls and this combination of validate and jQuery, so I figured it would be worth mentioning.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would of never figured that  out on my own! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a complete answer, but could be a step in the right direction. Using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) it seems on your other pages when I click specials, it makes a request to http://www.toberua.com/~new/specials however on the contact-us page the ajax request is instead going to http://www.toberua.com/~new/contact-us (which of course is not json)

One other interesting note: 
The XMLHttpRequest on other pages sets the Accept header properly (i.e. `Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01` , whereas on the contact-us page it is set to `Accept   */*`). I'd bet there's a different code branch being invoked...

Comment: Thanks, I figured that part out already. Just need to know now, why?